# How to setup winston logger for complex application?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

How to get **log4j**-like logger system in nodejs eco? As we can see *winston* is the most extended logger framework in nodejs. But we can't get exactly result with it to. Can you share your best practice logger subsystem?

It would be ideal if we get log4j-like logger use case:

**main.js**

```
// configuring loggers "Class A", "Class B", "Class C"
```

**ClassA.js**

```
// get fully configured logger "Class A" from factory. Have not any logger configuration inside class
// use logger
```

**ClassB.js**

```
// get fully configured logger "Class B" from factory. Have not any logger configuration inside class
// use logger
```

**ClassC.js**

```
// get fully configured logger "Class C" from factory. Have not any logger configuration inside class
// use logger
```

We would like to get log into console and rotated files

> date [LEVEL] loggerName: message
>
> date [LEVEL] loggerName: message
>
> date [LEVEL] loggerName: message
>
> ...